# Prevent Samsung's stock Messaging app from converting textual emoticon to emoji

Tags: sms, emoticons

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S8+ on Android 7.0 Nougat. When I send a classic emoticon in the text on the stock Messaging app, like one of these:

```
:-)
;-)
:-P
```

they will be displayed as an Android head, similar to one of these:

[image: Android-head Emoticons]

A couple of questions about this:

1. Is this just something that happens locally on my phone, or is the recipient seeing the same thing?
2. How do I disable the function in my default SMS app?

I personally find it a bit annoying that the conversion only appears *after* the message is sent. So, I have no way of knowing that my textual emoticons are going to be supplanted during composition.

Please note: I'm not interested in using a third-party (non-Google/Samsung) SMS app, and I don't want to root my phone.

Comment: Just want to clarify that Samsung's Messaging app is not the same as [Google's (default) Messaging app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging). That said, it might be helpful if you can mention the exact app name, since there's also another stock app from Verizon which is called "Message+".

Comment: Related: [How do I disable all emoticons on incoming/outgoing text messages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/126366/44325)

Answer (score 0):

Open the message app, then back out of any open text message until you get to the message history list. Open the menu from the top-left icon, scroll down and select "Settings." There should be an option titled "Enable Smart Emojis." Turn that off and hopefully this fixes your problem.

Comment: I've been all through the settings menu here and I don't see it.

Comment: Looks like "Enable Smart Emojis" is a feature available on Verizon's Messaging app (called Message+), not globally.