# Google Messages adds spaces to emoticons

Tags: sms, motorola, emoticons, google-messages

Since past 3-6 months [Android Messages app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) started to insert spaces between characters of my emoticons and also started to remove certain characters, causing garbage to be actually sent:

[image]

In addition to Google Messages, I am using [Gboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin) on both devices, so maybe this is a problem with the keyboard app, not with the messaging app.

Does anyone know what is this and how to prevent this?

At first I thought that this is a problem with my very old Motorla Moto One (first edition, X1941). But now I have migrated to Neffos X9 and I am observing exactly the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is caused by the "use simple characters" setting on Android Messages app.** The setting will convert special characters in SMS messages.

This is due to the possibility that *the recipient's messaging app converts the smileys into respecting emoji*, thus resulting in an incomprehensible message, like *when the sender intends to send the symbols as-is* instead of being considered as an emoticon.

Related questions demonstrating the issue:

- [How do I disable all emoticons on incoming/outgoing text messages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/126366/44325)
- [Prevent Samsung's stock Messaging app from converting textual emoticon to emoji](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/175088/44325)

Comment: Wasn't "use simple characters" setting meant to control whether national characters are converted into Latin counterparts? I intentionally enabled the setting that you're talking about, but I was 300% sure that I am enabling the feature of national characters conversion.

Comment: @trejder that's also one of the purposes. Basically it makes the SMS (which by default only supports the limited [GSM 03.38 character sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38)) save for the SMS provider (wrong encoding, e.g. due to emoji) and recipients (client-side emoji conversion).

Comment: I have accepted your answer, because you have explained everything perfectly. However, I must admit that this is as stupid as it can be. I've been using this switch (to replace national characters into simple Latin characters) for as long as I have been using Andriod phones, so ~10 years now. And they've only introduced adding spaces inside emoticons only a couple of months ago. Was that too hard to make that being controlled by two separate switches? Now, I can only choose: to have emoticons and send expensive 2-3 SMS long messages (even though text itself is short) or disable both at once.